# Virtual Machine Ubuntu 13.04 is Very Slow

Tags: 13.04, virtualization, vmware

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 in my VMWare (I'm using Windows 7); the problem is it's quite slow; it doesn't response quickly as opposed to native installed OS. I also installed CentOS & WinXP; they're working fast as if they are not virtual machine. What should I do?

Comment: Have you installed VMware Tools?

Comment: What are your system specifications?

Comment: See this related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/unity-low-gfx-mode-not-working-in-13-04

Comment: have you install vmware guest tools ?