# virtual Box on Mac running slow

Tags: virtualbox

I am having an issue , I’m using Virtual box  to run Ubuntu, its very slow and I gave it 1 gb of ram I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. I heard that Ubuntu flies and from the tutorial I saw online it did. I’m running the new 13.04 ..please help thank you . What I have done thus far is the basics , I went over my settings to see if I configured them as per the tutorial . Everything seems right .

Comment: Link to the tutorial you saw online?

Comment: did you install the virtualbox guest-additions on the ubuntu ?

Comment: This is a known issue. VirtualBox isn't able to handle the graphical effects of Ubuntu right, which makes it slow. If you want to use Ubuntu, you will have to not do it in VirtualBox.

Comment: @Emmanuel That doesn't matter. I have the same issue, both with and without guest additions.

Comment: @com.BOY it seems to be related to Unity 3D, since guest additions are installed did you check the "3D" box ?

Comment: Try the tweaks I outlined there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/unity-low-gfx-mode-not-working-in-13-04

Comment: @Emmanuel Yeah I know it's caused by Unity 3D. I did check the 3D box but that didn't help.

Comment: @Emmanuel You should post your comment as an answer so we can up-vote it and get it marked as the answer.