# How to enable Unity 3D support in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit virtual box with host Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, video

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox with host Windows 7 64 bit both
but video is a kind of choppy in both vlc & movie player and
Ubuntu is running slow,few seconds lagging in every click I do

I installed `build-essentials`, vbox guest additions and vbox extension , enabled 3D acceleration but still `unity_support_test` results as *"No"* for not software rendered and Ubuntu 3d support just as below..

```
Not software rendered:    no 
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes
Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Help me in getting 3D support and run Ubuntu faster just as normal Host OS without choppy video . I have seen in my friends system those are enabled without graphics card in virtual box . how could this be achieved in my system ??

Comment: Try with these settings: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/how-to-improve-performance-of-virtualbox-when-unity-low-gfx-mode-is-not-working

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem since Unity came out, here is the solution that always works for me.

1. Enable 3D acceleration in VirtualBox for the machine
2. Provide adequate video memory
3. Boot the Ubuntu guest
4. ensure kernel headers is installed for your running kernel

   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
5. Mount vbox additions
6. Install Guest Additions, it should autostart, if not run it from a sudo command prompt

   sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
7. Ensure that the word 'vboxvideo' appears on a line on it's own in /etc/modules
8. Reboot
9. Test with sudo /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

This ensures the vbox video driver is built correctly and installed for your current running kernel.

Note, if you ever do an apt-get dist-upgrade you will need to repeat this process as your kernel version might change.