# Virtualbox 3D acceleration doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, virtualbox, 64-bit, 3d

I'm running 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 as Virtualbox guest, host is Windows 7 64 bit. Ubuntu works slowly if I disable 3D acceleration in Virtualbox and painfully slowly if I enable it. I have followed advices from this reply [How to enable Unity 3D support in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit virtual box with host Windows 7 64 bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328459/how-to-enable-unity-3d-support-in-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-virtual-box-with-host-wind)
and Unity 3D seems to be set up right, but performance is very poor. [image: screenshot of the Unity test].

Any ideas what to try next?

Addition: When I enable 3D acceleration and write something in the terminal, text appears there only after I click somewhere outside terminal window.

Comment: You can try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/how-to-improve-performance-of-virtualbox-when-unity-low-gfx-mode-is-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the link Takkat, but unfortunately those didn't help either.