# Install Ubuntu 13.10 in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I want to install ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386 in Oracle VirtualBox on my HP laptop,
which has Windows 7 32-bit installed. I tried to install it, but it has problems like:

1. Internal error when I login in to my system.
2. After the installation is completed, it asks me to restart. When I restart, VirtualBox suddenly stops working and the whole process crashes.

Comment: Did you try these solutions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371432/how-to-troubleshoot-booting-to-a-black-screen-on-virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

The question is too general since you did not provide the Internal error detail's
However you could try to download ubuntu images from the virtualboxes website. 
http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/