# Ubuntu Trusty Tahr runs slowly in Virtualbox, with 3D enabled

Tags: unity, graphics, virtualbox

I installed the latest Ubuntu in the latest Virtualbox. It is slow: frames are visible in animations and the mouse flickers.

This question is different from many others on the net that suggest enabling 3D support. 
"/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p" returns that Unity 3D IS supported. 
Everything seems as it is supposed to be.

In Virtualbox 3D acceleration is enabled, 2D acceleration is greyed out (absent). I gave it 64MB of video RAM.

This is on an i5 with HD Graphics 2500, on W8.1+update plus latest HD drivers. Nothing uncommon: this should be in the Ubuntu release notes.

Comment: Try the solutions I gave here http://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/how-to-improve-performance-of-virtualbox-when-unity-low-gfx-mode-is-not-working - most of all install the [guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)

Comment: I did have Guest Additions installed and had already set Window Animations OFF (through the Unity Tweak Tool). Seems rather hopeless, is that correct? I just want a functional OS, no bling and no slowdowns. Thank you!

Comment: actually it should perform much better on your specs... it may be some machine settings you need to make.

Comment: would installing Mir make the difference?