# why is my ubuntu vm so slow? 16.04.3

Tags: virtualization

im running ubuntu 16.04.3 vm on vitual box and my pc specs are 16 gigs of ram amd7800k at 4gh. i have virtual box running on 2 of 4 processors. i have 3.5 gigs of ram allocated to the vm. and i have tried higher with no noticable results. overall the input is laggy and even youtube videos seem to lag alot. i really only have this vm installed to learn c language, so i am really only running youtube videos and  vim. any suggestions on what to try? i feel my machine should be more than capable of running the vm no problem.

thanks!

Comment: Watch videos from a Virtual Box is not a so good experience. You must enable video-acceleration and install Guest-Additions to improve video performance.

Comment: Also worth a try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/how-to-improve-performance-of-virtualbox-when-unity-low-gfx-mode-is-not-working